# Memory Size Load and Store penalty analysis?

Tags: c, pointers, memory, casting, cpu-cycles

Profiling the code with ocount shows  more cycles with penalty on and lesser cycles with penalty off. I'm trying to understand why there is more penalty when the penalty flag is on?

```
uint16_t arr[1010];
uint32_t r[500];


void func()
{     
            uint32_t i = 0;


            for (i = 0; i < 1000; i+=2)
            {
                arr[i] = i;
                arr[i+1] = i+10;
        #ifdef PENALTY_ON

               r[i/2] = *(uint32_t *)((uint16_t *)&arr[i+1]);
        #endif
            }
        #ifndef PENALTY_ON
            for (i = 0; i < 1000; i+=2)
            {
                r[i/2] = *(uint32_t *)((uint16_t *)&arr[i+1]);
            }
        #endif
 }
```

Comment: As a guess, prefetching? Without the penalty you can prefetch the entire `arr` array without interruption.

Comment: Are all those casts necessary? They're extremely noisy and distracting. And it's unclear whether one can meaningfully discuss the performance of undefined behaviour.

Comment: Actually the one who simulated it ,did that. I also am questioning the casts done here.

Comment: What processor architecture are you running the code on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compiling both with gcc on a 32-bit machine with -O3

With PENALTY_ON

```
00000000 <func>:
0:  31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
2:  8d b6 00 00 00 00       lea    0x0(%esi),%esi
8:  8d 50 0a                lea    0xa(%eax),%edx
b:  66 89 94 00 02 00 00    mov    %dx,0x2(%eax,%eax,1)
12: 00 
13: 8b 8c 00 02 00 00 00    mov    0x2(%eax,%eax,1),%ecx
1a: 89 c2                   mov    %eax,%edx
1c: 66 89 84 00 00 00 00    mov    %ax,0x0(%eax,%eax,1)
23: 00 
24: 83 c0 02                add    $0x2,%eax
27: d1 ea                   shr    %edx
29: 3d e8 03 00 00          cmp    $0x3e8,%eax
2e: 89 0c 95 00 00 00 00    mov    %ecx,0x0(,%edx,4)
35: 75 d1                   jne    8 <func+0x8>
37: f3 c3                   repz ret
```

Without PENALTY_ON

```
00000000 <func>:
0:  31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
2:  8d b6 00 00 00 00       lea    0x0(%esi),%esi
8:  8d 50 0a                lea    0xa(%eax),%edx
b:  66 89 84 00 00 00 00    mov    %ax,0x0(%eax,%eax,1)
12: 00 
13: 66 89 94 00 02 00 00    mov    %dx,0x2(%eax,%eax,1)
1a: 00 
1b: 83 c0 02                add    $0x2,%eax
1e: 3d e8 03 00 00          cmp    $0x3e8,%eax
23: 75 e3                   jne    8 <func+0x8>
25: 66 31 c0                xor    %ax,%ax
28: 8b 8c 00 02 00 00 00    mov    0x2(%eax,%eax,1),%ecx
2f: 89 c2                   mov    %eax,%edx
31: 83 c0 02                add    $0x2,%eax
34: d1 ea                   shr    %edx
36: 3d e8 03 00 00          cmp    $0x3e8,%eax
3b: 89 0c 95 00 00 00 00    mov    %ecx,0x0(,%edx,4)
42: 75 e4                   jne    28 <func+0x28>
44: f3 c3                   repz ret
```

I think the reason is that a Read-after-Write stall occurs with `PENALTY_ON`

```
b:  66 89 94 00 02 00 00    mov    %dx,0x2(%eax,%eax,1)
12: 00 
13: 8b 8c 00 02 00 00 00    mov    0x2(%eax,%eax,1),%ecx
```

Comment: That could be it. is it store to load forwarding issue?

Comment: Yes, I believe so. As I understood it, store-to-load forwarding requires alignments to match.